# Template Syntax in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I don't understand templates really and was trying to run a simple find the minimum for ints, doubles, chars.

First question, why is `template<typename T>` sometimes used, and other times `template<>`?

Second question, I do not know what I am doing wrong with the following code below:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T minimum(T arg1, T arg2)
{
    return arg1 < arg2 ? arg1 : arg2;
}

template <typename T>
// first I tried template <> instd of above, but wasn't sure the difference
T minimum<const char *>(const char *arg1, const char *arg2)
{
    return strcmp(arg1, arg2) ? arg2 : arg1;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << minimum<int>(4, 2) << '\n';
    std::cout << minimum<double>(2.2, -56.7) << '\n';
    std::cout << minimum(2.2, 2) << '\n';
}

Compile Errors:
 error C2768: 'minimum' : illegal use of explicit template arguments
 error C2783: 'T minimum(const char *,const char *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'T'
 : see declaration of 'minimum'
 : error C2782: 'T minimum(T,T)' : template parameter 'T' is ambiguous
 : see declaration of 'minimum'
```

Third, in getting familiar with separating .h and .cpp files, if I wanted this minimum() function to be a static function of my class, but it was the only function in that class, would I have to have a template class as well?  I originally tried doing it that way instead of having it all in one file and I got some compile errors as well that I can't remember right now and was unsure how I would do that.  Thanks!

Comment: May I suggest looking up a templated min<> function on Google?  This is one of the first examples given for this type of function so there should be an abundance of code samples availalb.e

Comment: Just so you don't feel too frustrated (or maybe this will make you more frustrated...), C++'s template syntax and semantics are among the most complex areas of the language, and that's saying something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your question is almost answered, but you still have a couple of outstanding issues...

```
std::cout << minimum(2.2, 2) << '\n';
```

This won't compile with the two template functions you have provided as there is no matching function for call to `minimum(double, int)`. This leaves you two options:

You can change your first template function to be:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T minimum(T arg1, U arg2)
{
    return arg1 < arg2 ? arg1 : arg2;
}
```

*or*

You can change your code to specify which specialisation to invoke:

```
std::cout << minimum<double>(2.2, 2) << '\n';
```

There is also a bug in your `const char*` specialisation (once the syntax error is resolved) since a zero return value from `strcmp` indicates that both strings are equal. The following assertion will fail:

```
assert(0 == strcmp("aaa", minimum("aaa", "bbb")));
```

This can be fixed thus:

```
template <>
const char* minimum<const char*>(const char* arg1, const char* arg2)
{
    return strcmp(arg1, arg2) > 0 ? arg2 : arg1;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I don't quite see how it fails.  You are correct that it does when I checked it with aaa and bbb, but I don't see why....  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you need to get (and study) a book the covers templates -- it looks like you need to learn far too much of the basics to cover in an answer here.

The `template<>` syntax is used for template specialization. For what you apparently want, you'd do something like this:

```
template <class T>
T minimum(T const &a, T const &b) {
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

template<>
char const *minimum<char const *>(char const *a, char const *b) { 
    return strcmp(a, b) ? a : b;
}
```

Generally speaking, however, this is really the wrong thing to do -- instead of providing specializations for `char const *`, you *usually* want to just use `std::string`, which provides an `operator<` so your first version would work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
template <>
const char* minimum<const char *>(const char *arg1, const char *arg2)
{
    return strcmp(arg1, arg2) ? arg2 : arg1;
}
```

Comment: Can templates have different return types?  I tried that and got this error:
 error C2782: 'T minimum(T,T)' : template parameter 'T' is ambiguous
1>         see declaration of 'minimum'
1>        could be 'int'
1>        or       'double'

Comment: Did you try my code?  Your original had "T" as the return type in the original specialization.

Answer (score 2):

Lets tackle that first question. You want to review Template Specialization, and it was your syntax that was off:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T minimum(T arg1, T arg2)
{
    return arg1 < arg2 ? arg1 : arg2;
}

template<> const char * minimum<const char *>(const char *arg1, const char *arg2)
{
    return strcmp(arg1, arg2) ? arg2 : arg1;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << minimum<int>(4, 2) << '\n';
    std::cout << minimum<double>(2.2, -56.7) << '\n';
    std::cout << minimum(2.2, 2.0) << '\n';
}
```

Once you wrap your head around that, I bet you can get the rest to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your const char* specialization is incorrect. You have it return any type T. This is not supported by your function which returns a const char*.  Basically you can't half do the specialization either T is specialized or it isn't. If it is specialized then it shouldn't appear in the template<> list.  If it isn't specialized then it should be in the template list.